# How to format output of antiword in php

Tags: php

I'm using antiword to read doc files in php:

```
<?php
$filename = 'sample.doc';
$content = shell_exec('C:\\wamp\\www\\tester\\read_documents\\antiword\\antiword '.$filename);
echo $content;
?>
```

Is it possible to format the output?

Comment: ..what's the output? How do you want to format it?

Comment: You don't need to escape the \ in single quoted strings. Only if it comes before the closing '. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: You could also use the `-x db` flag to turn it into a docbook document, and then reformat that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[manual page of antiword](http://linux.die.net/man/1/antiword) says:

> -f  Output in formatted text form. That means that bold text is printed
>   like *bold*, italics like /italics/
>   and underlined text as _underlined_.
>   -p papersize  Output in PostScript form. Printable on paper of the
>   specified size: 10x14, a3, a4, a5, b4,
>   b5, executive, folio, legal, letter,
>   note, quarto, statement or tabloid.
>   -t  Output in text form. (default)
>   -x document type definition  Output in XML form. Currently the only document
>   type definition is db (for DocBook).

So, you can choose various output formats; by default, antiword strips out all formatting. I'd guess you want the `-f` option, and possibly replace that simple formatting into HTML tags.

Comment: so how then do I format it if its already in *bold* /italics/ form?